# TLS Handshake with different JDK

Tags: java, encryption

I'm using two versions of java JDK provided by Oracle:

1. `1.8.0_151`
2. `1.8.0_221`

to query a SQL Server 2008 instance. The handshake is not performed correctly with the second version. Enabling the handshake stack trace with `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` the error message is:

```
System property jdk.tls.client.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
System property jdk.tls.server.cipherSuites is set to 'null'
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_DES_CBC_40_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_EXPORT_WITH_RC4_40_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DH_anon_EXPORT_WITH_DES40_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Ignoring disabled cipher suite: SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
update handshake state: client_hello[1]
upcoming handshake states: server_hello[2]
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1578925673 bytes = { 208, 162, 55, 220, 191, 155, 118, 25, 213, 224, 148, 178, 223, 86, 184, 159, 1, 62, 243, 22, 235, 7, 80, 228, 45, 146, 27, 228 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 189
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
main, called closeSocket(true)
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 5
main, received EOFException: ignored
main, called closeInternal(false)
main, close invoked again; state = 5
main, handling exception: java.io.IOException: SQL Server no devolvió una respuesta. Se ha cerrado la conexión. ClientConnectionId:76ffe542-f83e-4942-8554-e8a8b1496539
main, called closeSocket()
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException
```

However the first version works without problems:

```
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DH_anon_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
Ignoring unavailable cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
trigger seeding of SecureRandom
done seeding SecureRandom
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
Ignoring unsupported cipher suite: TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 for TLSv1.1
%% No cached client session
*** ClientHello, TLSv1.2
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1578921892 bytes = { 243, 166, 223, 82, 23, 20, 225, 53, 226, 148, 62, 216, 182, 250, 39, 212, 218, 77, 54, 180, 167, 69, 180, 223, 132, 214, 53, 228 }
Session ID:  {}
Cipher Suites: [TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_DHE_DSS_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, SSL_DHE_DSS_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA, TLS_EMPTY_RENEGOTIATION_INFO_SCSV]
Compression Methods:  { 0 }
Extension elliptic_curves, curve names: {secp256r1, secp384r1, secp521r1, sect283k1, sect283r1, sect409k1, sect409r1, sect571k1, sect571r1, secp256k1}
Extension ec_point_formats, formats: [uncompressed]
Extension signature_algorithms, signature_algorithms: SHA512withECDSA, SHA512withRSA, SHA384withECDSA, SHA384withRSA, SHA256withECDSA, SHA256withRSA, SHA256withDSA, SHA1withECDSA, SHA1withRSA, SHA1withDSA
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 161
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 604
*** ServerHello, TLSv1
RandomCookie:  GMT: 1578922290 bytes = { 53, 71, 157, 126, 84, 176, 39, 238, 170, 229, 171, 60, 169, 152, 32, 53, 102, 110, 173, 9, 97, 146, 41, 80, 168, 199, 140, 203 }
Session ID:  {133, 36, 0, 0, 53, 91, 90, 53, 70, 196, 180, 188, 211, 121, 162, 139, 90, 141, 34, 174, 179, 250, 83, 86, 147, 84, 143, 188, 160, 118, 146, 233}
Cipher Suite: SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
Compression Method: 0
Extension renegotiation_info, renegotiated_connection: <empty>
***
%% Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
** SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
*** Certificate chain
chain [0] = [
[
  Version: V3
  Subject: CN=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
  Signature Algorithm: SHA1withRSA, OID = 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5

  Key:  Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits
  modulus: 130318874926176396059797416865057748902639541061882103828501959370067450721622767134179270248129273853999036842276016316663835262785868933808651538537810919161245508235593661460294952889286799800748410726304576478980790365354263215021894321477308037749567614899486149521850502651902173949549603400520144346343
  public exponent: 65537
  Validity: [From: Thu Mar 28 19:08:19 CET 2019,
               To: Sun Mar 28 20:08:19 CEST 2049]
  Issuer: CN=SSL_Self_Signed_Fallback
  SerialNumber: [    6e5e2ee1 a57746a3 43753348 4f2fe70d]

]
  Algorithm: [SHA1withRSA]
  Signature:
0000: 8F 1B F8 07 63 3A 04 D7   4D 0B D8 12 F2 7C 02 8F  ....c:..M.......
0010: F5 FB 9F FD 6B 2D 16 CB   9B F5 AC 64 42 82 FD 1A  ....k-.....dB...
0020: 9A EA B9 D3 85 C6 B6 50   E1 D6 55 7C 2E 6F 8B DF  .......P..U..o..
0030: 41 B7 B3 9E F6 A3 02 D3   9D 5D 9E 55 E3 33 8B 6D  A........].U.3.m
0040: 77 63 33 22 18 1D EF CF   E0 A5 E5 C4 9F 8F 06 01  wc3"............
0050: CA 97 58 86 29 C7 F5 5E   DC 66 F3 32 C4 29 B2 4D  ..X.)..^.f.2.).M
0060: 3B 22 79 12 4E D5 4D 28   40 2A C3 44 21 B1 BE C0  ;"y.N.M(@*.D!...
0070: DB 3C F5 DE FD 71 E5 A5   DB D0 27 61 65 CE A8 27  .<...q....'ae..'

]
***
*** ServerHelloDone
*** ClientKeyExchange, RSA PreMasterSecret, TLSv1
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 134
SESSION KEYGEN:
PreMaster Secret:
0000: 03 03 03 33 9A D8 D3 20   72 12 18 17 F5 4C 53 B7  ...3... r....LS.
0010: E8 8C 7B 37 7F 6C 4A 2D   45 1B E1 2D 00 16 DB 55  ...7.lJ-E..-...U
0020: C2 72 C6 94 AA B6 A0 08   10 27 93 DE 1A FA A1 EA  .r.......'......
CONNECTION KEYGEN:
Client Nonce:
0000: 5E 1C 70 A4 F3 A6 DF 52   17 14 E1 35 E2 94 3E D8  ^.p....R...5..>.
0010: B6 FA 27 D4 DA 4D 36 B4   A7 45 B4 DF 84 D6 35 E4  ..'..M6..E....5.
Server Nonce:
0000: 5E 1C 71 32 35 47 9D 7E   54 B0 27 EE AA E5 AB 3C  ^.q25G..T.'....<
0010: A9 98 20 35 66 6E AD 09   61 92 29 50 A8 C7 8C CB  .. 5fn..a.)P....
Master Secret:
0000: CE 0E 1A AD B5 1A F4 8B   5C CC 8E BD 9D 3B 60 29  ........\....;`)
0010: 6B 1B E0 AF 9F 69 8D B6   00 46 9D D0 52 9E AB 71  k....i...F..R..q
0020: D6 7F 86 A4 4F 30 F5 F1   EC CF C8 E3 0B CB 55 40  ....O0........U@
Client MAC write Secret:
0000: A0 8A 98 92 67 BD EA BC   82 4F FD 50 B8 FB D6 AA  ....g....O.P....
0010: 27 F9 62 FC                                        '.b.
Server MAC write Secret:
0000: 0C EA 85 99 A0 B1 B6 FE   17 66 09 AA 9A 2F 59 CE  .........f.../Y.
0010: 17 71 E7 74                                        .q.t
Client write key:
0000: 9D 85 CD 1F AD 28 FF AE   A2 B8 3A 92 2B B2 3F 4D  .....(....:.+.?M
0010: C5 C7 52 34 69 E6 5E 6D                            ..R4i.^m
Server write key:
0000: 38 B6 CE AC 72 70 DF 79   6F 38 F2 5B AA 41 82 0E  8...rp.yo8.[.A..
0010: 15 39 A7 B5 4C FC 97 F9                            .9..L...
Client write IV:
0000: 08 67 19 0B 7C 25 BF F6                            .g...%..
Server write IV:
0000: C2 89 A1 02 EC 5A 0D 6A                            .....Z.j
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 158, 116, 144, 110, 132, 65, 168, 29, 207, 60, 130, 62 }
***
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40
main, READ: TLSv1 Change Cipher Spec, length = 1
main, READ: TLSv1 Handshake, length = 40
*** Finished
verify_data:  { 123, 213, 13, 100, 252, 230, 56, 239, 22, 41, 108, 75 }
***
%% Cached client session: [Session-1, SSL_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA]
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Application Data, length = 336
main, called close()
main, called closeInternal(true)
main, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
main, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 24
main, called closeSocket(true)
main, waiting for close_notify or alert: state 5
main, received EOFException: ignored
main, called closeInternal(false)
main, close invoked again; state = 5
Finalizer, called close()
Finalizer, called closeInternal(true)
```

The jdbc connector version used is `7.0.0.jre8`

The exception `main, handling exception: java.io.IOException: SQL Server no devolvió una respuesta. Se ha cerrado la conexión. ClientConnectionId:76ffe542-f83e-4942-8554-e8a8b1496539"` is caused by the TLS Handshake failure.

Which is the difference between these two handshakes?

Kind regards

Comment: "main, handling exception: java.io.IOException: SQL Server no devolvió una respuesta. Se ha cerrado la conexión. ClientConnectionId:76ffe542-f83e-4942-8554-e8a8b1496539"?

Comment: SQL Server is configured in spanish. Its an SQL Server exception that is thrown using the `1.8.0_221` JDK. The jdbc connector version used is `7.0.0.jre8`

Comment: Yeah, is the Exception the cause for the error or is the error the cause for the Exception?

Comment: The TLS error is the cause for the exception.

Comment: Try to install 'Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files ' https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html as you're using 1024bits encrypted key: 'Sun RSA public key, 1024 bits'